# Favicon shows in home page but not in inner pages

Tags: wordpress, favicon

In few of my websites the favicon is shown correctly on home page and some inner pages. But in some other inner pages they are not shown. This is a wordpress based site and uses wordpress Network.

Shows here: http://www.bcmazda.com

Does not appear here: http://usedcars.bcmazda.com/bcmazdav2/browse/view_detailed/type_used/

If you look at the source, it has favicon correctly linked.

Comment: it is appearing at this link too
http://usedcars.bcmazda.com/bcmazdav2/browse/view_detailed/type_used/

Comment: For a month or so I hv been checking and I am not seeing it. Can you show me a screen shot or something that it does show.

Comment: Whoa, you've got a full HTML document within another on your listed subpage. Your WordPress theme seems f***. 

The doc in doc starts here
`<div id="inventorypage">
<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: are you using iFrame for any reason?